# How to get or set degree of parallelism for a powershell workflow

Tags: powershell

When using powershell workflows with multiple servers specified in the `PSComputerName` parameter, how can I control the maximum number of servers the workflow executes on at a single time?

Just to be clear, I'm not talking about `Parallel` activities, but rather the workflow itself. E.G:

```
workflow Test-ParallelWorkflow {
    InlineScript {
        Write-Information "$($PSCOMPUTERNAME): Doing stuff"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        Write-Information "$($PSCOMPUTERNAME): Finished doing stuff"
    }
}

$arrayWithHundredsOfServers = @(...)
Test-ParallelWorkflow -PSComputerName $arrayWithHundredsOfServers
```

I can't find anything in the documentation, so I assume the only way to control this is to limit the number of servers I pass into the array. However, I'm sure there must be some internal throttling to handle situations where hundreds / thousands of servers are passed in.

Comment: See this previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577975/powershell-3-0-workflows-limit-number-of-parallel-execution